# SQL запрос с выборкой суммы из одной таблицы в одно поле в другой

Tags: sql, база-данных, join

Доброе время суток! Хотел бы спросить, если мне ответят.

Есть задача в одной таблице одним запросом сделать вывод стоимости тех.обслуживания конкретного ID_Акта. Загвостка в том, что я имею несколько услуг в одном акте, из-за этого я вынес это все таблицей с промежуточным значением.

Пробовал сделать JOIN c условием M.Стоимость = (SELECT SUM(Стоимость) FROM [Перечень работы] AS B JOIN Услуги AS H ON B.ID_Услуги = H.ID_Услуги WHERE M.ID_Акта = B.ID_Акта)

Отдельно запрос все суммирует в одну строчку, которая мне как раз и нужна в этом запросе, но я не могу его перенести, просто уже голова ломается.

СУБД: MS SQL Server

Структура таблиц:

Услуги:
ID_Услуги (int), Название(nvarchar(50)), Стоимость (decimal(6, 2))

Перечень работы:
ID_Акта(int), ID_Услуги(int)

Приемо-сдаточный акт:
ID_Акта(int), ID_Клиента(int), ID_Авто(int), Цвет(nvarchar(20)), ID_Сотрудника(int), Стоимость(decimal(7, 2))

Запрос нужно доработать:

```
USE ДоброДляАвто SELECT M.ID_Акта AS [Номер акта], K.Фамилия + ' ' + K.Имя + ' ' + K.Отчество AS [ФИО Клиента], 
                                     N.Название + ' ' + A.Название AS Авто, M.[Цвет авто], M.[Дата приема], 
                                     M.[Дата сдачи], P.Фамилия + ' ' + P.Имя + ' ' + P.Отчество AS [ФИО Сотрудника], 
                                     M.Стоимость 
FROM [Приемо-сдаточный акт] AS M
JOIN Клиенты AS K ON K.Фамилия + ' ' + K.Имя + ' ' + K.Отчество = (SELECT K.Фамилия + ' ' + K.Имя + ' ' + K.Отчество 
                                                                    WHERE K.ID_Клиента = M.ID_Клиента)
JOIN Сотрудник AS P ON P.Фамилия + ' ' + P.Имя + ' ' + P.Отчество = (SELECT P.Фамилия + ' ' + P.Имя + ' ' + P.Отчество 
                                                                    WHERE P.ID_Сотрудника = M.ID_Сотрудника)
JOIN Авто AS A ON A.Название = (SELECT A.Название WHERE A.ID_Марка = M.ID_Авто) 
JOIN Марка AS N ON N.Название = (SELECT N.Название WHERE N.ID_Марка = M.ID_Авто);
```

Запрос готовый отдельно от всей таблицы:

```
SELECT SUM(Стоимость) FROM [Перечень работы] AS M 
JOIN Услуги AS U ON U.ID_Услуги = M.ID_Услуги
WHERE ID_Акта = 1;
```

Пример данных:

Услуги:

```
ID_Услуги = 1;
Название = Смена тормозной системы;
Стоимость = 10000

ID_Услуги = 2;
Название = Смена шины;
Стоимость = 1000
```

Перечень работы:

```
ID_Акта = 1;
ID_Услуги = 1

ID_Акта = 1;
ID_Услуги = 2
```

Приемо-сдаточный акт:

```
ID_Акта = 1;
ID_Клиента = 1;
ID_Авто = 1;
ID_Сотрудника = 1;
Стоимость = (Нужно из промежуточной таблицы по "ID_Услуги" взять все их стоимости и сммировать в одну ячейку для данной)
```

Желательно сделать через JOIN.

Comment: Особо не знаток SQL да и программирования, но вот об заклад бился, так и не понял, как мне JOIN сделать так, чтобы он обьеденил с начало таблицу "Услуги" с "Перечень работы", а потом уже он обьеденялся с "Актом", чтобы выбрать оттуда SUM(Стоимости).

За ранее спасибо за ответы и правки.

Comment: Ваш комментарий добавьте в вопрос. Так же структуру таблиц добавьте текстом. Скрины трудно читать и скопировать данные не возможно, что бы поиграться и дать вам ответ

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Не знаю толком как тут делать с интерфейсом, но попытался изложить основное для формирования задачи.

Comment: Единственное, что может решить проблему, но уже будет походить на очень смачный костыль - добавить поле "Стоимость" в промежуточную таблицу, чтобы убрать лишний JOIN из запроса и сразу считать SUM (Стоимость) FROM [Перечень работы]

Comment: Укажите СУБД, которую используете. Покажите структуру таблиц, можно без промежуточных. Укажите пример данных. Покажите желательный вывод - тогда можно подсказать, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Cейчас заредачу

Comment: Очень коряво поправил, но как пока знаю сайт и инструменты описал что есть. Необезательная информация по клиентам, авто и сотрудникам. Главное сделать суммирование по промежуточной таблице, чтобы потом выводило при SELECT одну единную сумму взятую из "Перечень работы" по данному ID_Акта, которые выводиться в таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы в эту ячейку запихнуть функцию суммы, надо было просто в начальном SELECT уже указать данный вариант использования.

```
USE ДоброДляАвто SELECT M.ID_Акта AS [Номер акта], K.Фамилия + ' ' + K.Имя + ' ' + K.Отчество AS [ФИО Клиента], 
                                     N.Название + ' ' + A.Название AS Авто, M.[Цвет авто], M.[Дата приема], 
                                     M.[Дата сдачи], P.Фамилия + ' ' + P.Имя + ' ' + P.Отчество AS [ФИО Сотрудника], 
                                     **(SELECT SUM(Стоимость) FROM [Перечень работы] WHERE ID_Акта = M.ID_Акта)**
```